# Updating data UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

whats the best way to refresh data in a UITableView, lets say data is populated at start-up then this data changes, how could i refresh the data, every 30 seconds or give the option of the user to refresh the data.

i can populate data but unsure on how to update the data when it has been put in the UITableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use timer `NSTimer` to update you `UITabelView` after each 30 second.

Use `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 30.0 target: self
                                   selector: @selector(callAfterThirtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

After each 30.0 second , iOS will call the below function

Make `isStopUdating` as class member just like `UITabelView` instance : if you want to discontinue of updating table  then set `isStopUdating` with YES,

```
-(void) callAfterThirtySecond:(NSTimer*) timer 
{

    if(isStopUdating)
    {
         [timer invalidate];
    } 
    [myTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Once you invalidate timer you won't call every time

Answer (score 2):

[self.tableView reloadData];

after you update/change you data

Answer (score 0):

If You Update regularly means
Use This
`NSTimer * timerFade = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(get) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

and

`-(void) get
{
your url process

> [self.tableview reload data];

}

if you give the option for user  You may directly call

> [self get];

Comment: can get be called anything or is a specific method which apple provide and i assume the NSTimer is put in the app delegate.

Comment: @ Mintuz You use any name.This is my coding.i am using get in my project